# Button should get clicked only once for each record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button

I created a Button from Buttons,links.The button is placed in the detail page,That button should get clicked only once for each record.How can this possible.

Regards,
Usha

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Can you add those details into your question as well?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your button? If it is "Execute Javascript", then on the click of button, you can update a custom boolean field from false to true. For example, create a custom field called "isButtonClicked" with default value of false. When user clicks on button, check the value of this field. If it is false, then toggle it to true and allow the user to do the action. If the value is already true, then display an error message.

For updating the field value, you need to use sforce.apex.execute